# How do I end my recursion after a certain amount of time in Java?

Tags: java, search, time, tree

I am doing a game tree search with alpha beta pruning in a game similar to checkers, but I am given a strict 5 second limit on determining my best move.  I would like my recursion to enter the base case right before the allotted time is up.

How can I check to see how much time I have left, or maybe change a Boolean when my time is nearly done?

Comment: just an idea.Take a static variable and use according to your requirement.

Comment: Is there a built in java class you would recommend using to track the time? How would you implement it? Also, thanks for responding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at each step, use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the current time and compare that to a time that you saved before the recursion started.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new thread that would count and on 5 seconds change a boolean which can be checked from somewhere else . Something like that maybe ?

```
Executors.newCachedThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                          Thread.sleep(5000);
                          timeout = true;
}});
```

Comment: So would I initialize timeout as false, run this right before I begin my rescission and then check if it's true in my base case?

Comment: Ye that would work. Also the solution by @dldnh would also work I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this. As suggested in other posts you could use `System.currentTimeMillis()`, and check it against a `long startTime` variable that you pass via the recursive call, or is somehow otherwise available to the recursive function as it executes. *Or* you could use a `Runnable` or `Callable` to flip a flag or run a callback after a 5000ms `sleep()`, but I think that might be overkill.

Last time *I* did something like this, I used a [Guava class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html) called `StopWatch`, which provides a nice method called `elapsedMillis()` which gives you the number of elapsed milliseconds since you started your `StopWatch`. This approach is most like the `System.currentTimeMillis()`, but requires slightly less boiler plate. If introducing Guava as a dependency is not an option, then you could always implement a similar class yourself, which under the hood would simply use `System.currentTimeMillis()` in any case.